# Create a text file using a batch script then opening the text file in the same batch instance

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch script that creates a text document in a specific location, and then opens the text file. When I run the script below, it just tells me it cannot find the txt file.

What I have so far.

```
@ECHO OFF

cls
color 0e
set title= "test"
cd %localhost%
echo hello > "%title%.txt"

START /WAIT test.txt
```

Comment: Where is your `specific location`? because there's no such variable, by default named `localhost` so that does not help us. If you want to write it to the current directory, then you do not need to provide a path to the file, `(Echo hello) 1> "test.txt"`, if you want to write it to the same directory as the batch file resides, then use `(Echo hello) 1> "%~dp0test.txt"`, if you want a specific location then use `(Echo hello) 1> "S:\pecific\Location\test.txt"`. You could also use the current directory, by changing it to your specific location first, e.g. `CD /D "S:\pecific\Location\test.txt"`

Comment: @Compo My problem is not the location at where it is written. My problem is that after the .txt file is written, when "START /WAIT test.txt" is run it tells me it cannot find "test.txt" and I am wondering why.

Comment: Perhaps that is because you've not used the recommended syntax for the `set` command `Set "title=test"`. Currently your command is expanding to `echo hello > " "test".txt"`, if you use the recommended syntax, it would read `echo hello > "test.txt"`. Although that would add `hello<SPACE>` to the file, not `hello`.

Comment: @Compo How exactly would that help solve my issue? It is unable to locate the txt file that is written by the batch script, but when starting other txt files through the batch it works fine.

Comment: it would help to create the file with the correct name. Take a closer look to your files: you created `" test.txt"` (yes, with the leading space). `"test.txt"` is simply not there, therefore you get "can not find the file".

Comment: @Stephan I can see the problem now, thank you. The txt file it is writing has a space in front of its name.

Comment: @Compo I am sorry, it was my fault. I did not understand what u were trying to explain to me at first. Now I can see that the syntax was incorrect. Thanks for the help ^^

Comment: If you take a look at my answer, it should show you how you could more correctly write your script. Line `3` shows you again the correct syntax for the `set` command, line `4`, changes drive and directory to `%localhost%`, if it exists, and if not exits the script. Line `5` writes the file and only if that is successful, _(it can fail if the current directory, does not permit the user to write there)_, opens the file in the default program associated  with `.txt` file handling, and waits until you close that opened program, before continuing with any remaining lines, or ending the script.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your posted code, this is what I assume it should look like, as long as `%localhost%` is a defined variable in the current environment when you run it!

```batch-file
@CLS
@COLOR 0E
@SET "title=test"
@CD /D "%localhost%" 2> NUL || EXIT /B
@(ECHO hello) 1> "%title%.txt" && "%title%.txt"
```

*If you don't need your script to wait until the text file viewer has been closed, you can use the `START` command, by changing `&& "%title%.txt"` on the last line to `&& START "" "%title%.txt"`*

Additionally, if your specific location, is on another PC, you may find that replacing the `CD` command with `PUSHD` is a better option for you:

```batch-file
@CLS
@COLOR 0E
@SET "title=test"
@PUSHD "%localhost%" 2> NUL || EXIT /B
@(ECHO hello) 1> "%title%.txt" && "%title%.txt"
@POPD
```

When you use `POPD` the current directory will revert to the one which was current, immediately prior to the point at which you used `PUSHD`.